How to measure a server process maximum memory usage from launch to SIGINT using /usr/bin/time in Python
I have a server program (let's call it my-server) I cannot alter and I am interested in measuring its maximum memory usage from when it starts to when a certain external event occurs.
I am able to do it manually on my shell by:

running /usr/bin/time -f "%M" my-server

triggering the external event

sending an INT signal to the process by pressing CTRL + C

reading the standard error


I'd like to do this programmatically using Python. If not possible I'd like to find an alternative simple way to achieve the same result.
I tried launching the same command as a subprocess and sending an INT signal to it:
import signal
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["/usr/bin/time", "-f", "%M", "my-server"],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True
)
# ...wait for external event
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
out, err = proc.communicate()  # both out and err are ""

however both out and err are empty.
The same script works fine for processes that terminate:
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["/usr/bin/time", "-f", "%M", "echo", "hello"],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True
)
out, err = proc.communicate()  # out is "hello", err is "1920"

but for processes that need to be terminated via signal I am not sure how to retrieve stderr after termination was issued. (or even before it, despite not useful)
The following somewhat equivalent example may be useful for testing:
terminate-me.py
import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('Terminated', file=sys.stderr) # Need to read this 
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print('Send SIGINT to terminate')
signal.pause()

main.py
import signal
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["python", "terminate-me.py"],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True
)
# No need to wait for any external event
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print(out)
print(err)


When you press Ctl-c it sends SIGINT to the entire foreground process group, not just the time process.

Thanks, I had assumed it was only sent to the time process and the time process handled it by sending the same signal to to the sub-process it was measuring, waited for it to terminate, then outputted before terminating. Instead it seems to me it does not send any signal to its sub-process and waits for it to terminate before outputting. What makes it work inside the shell is that the sub-process receives SIGINT and is able to terminate before time does. In my script I would then need to send SIGINT to the sub-process only. Does this mean that in my shell I'm relying on a race condition?

It turns out I misunderstood /usr/bin/time's behavior.
I thought that when receiving an INT signal time would relay it to its sub-process being measured, waited for it to terminate, and then terminated normally outputting its results.
What happens instead is that time simply terminates before outputting any result.
When executing within a shell, pressing CTRL + C actually sends an INT signal to both, but the sub-process terminates before time does, so time is able to complete its execution and it appears as if time awaited the sub-process.
Therefore in my script I was able to make it work by only sending the INT signal to the sub-process: (actually, to all of its sub-processes for simplicity)
import signal
import subprocess
import psutil

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["/usr/bin/time", "-f", "%M", "my-server"],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True
)

# Wait for external event...

children = psutil.Process(proc.pid).children()
for child in children:
    child.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
out, err = proc.communicate()


If I take your two sample snippets and modify the main.py and send the INT from outside I get output ... ?
cat main.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["/usr/bin/time","-f","%M","python", "terminate-me.py"],
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    text=True
)
out, err = proc.communicate()
print(out)
print(err)


cat terminate-me.py 
import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('Terminated', file=sys.stderr) # Need to read this 
    sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print('Send SIGINT to terminate')
signal.pause()

In a second terminal I find the processes PID and kill -INT PID and get this:
python main.py
Send SIGINT to terminate

Terminated
9732


You sent INT to the terminate-me process (not the time process), right?

Yup ... that.  Sorry, thought that was obvious from the question.
